# Accordion keeps user click panel open

Tags: jquery

When I use `jQuery` accordion in my menu, how do I keep the user click panel open when the page refreshes? The accordion always closes when the user clicks a panel, sending request and refreshing the page.

This is my code:

```
$(function(){
     var icons = {
        header: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
        activeHeader: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
         }

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle:"content",
            header:".level21",
    event:"click",
    active:false,
    collapsible:true,
    icons:icons
    });  
 });
```

Comment: session/local storage, server-side sessions, cookies, databases. All of these are ways of storing data about user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Hidden Fields` to maintain accordion state during postbacks.

I don't know which technology are you using, but for ASP.net

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidAccordionIndex" runat="server" Value="0" />


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var activeIndex = parseInt($('#<%=hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val());

        $("#accordion").accordion({
            autoHeight:false,
            event:"mousedown",
            active:activeIndex,
            change:function(event, ui)
            {
                var index = $(this).children('h3').index(ui.newHeader);
                $('#<%=hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val(index);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can use the JQuery cookies plugin [here](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie), then setting it's value as below

```
    change: function(event,ui) {
        var hid = ui.newHeader.children('a').attr('id');
    if (hid === undefined) {
        $.cookie('menustate', null);
    } else {
        $.cookie('menustate', hid, { expires: 2 });
    }
}
```

Useful article [here](http://www.mikecentola.com/blog/2009/05/31/saving-state-with-the-jquery-accordion-menu/)